# bash `[[` evaluation rules

Tags: bash, syntax, evaluation

It seems `[[` uses rather different evaluation rules that plain `test` (`[`) does.
However those rules are not properly described in the bash manual (IMHO).
Consider this example:

```bash
> a[1]=''
> i=1
> [[ -v a[i] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v a[$i] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v a[$j] ]] && echo true || echo false
false
> i=0
> [[ -v a[$i] ]] && echo true || echo false
false
> [[ -v ${a[$i]} ]] && echo true || echo false
false
> i=1
> [[ -v ${a[$i]} ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

So the question is:
*Where can I leave out the `$`, where must I use the `$`, and where can I use the `$` inside `[[` (without affecting the correct result)?

### On "*The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number*"

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/74401112/6607497 says (via https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)):

> The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number

It seems to me that when using associative arrays, then the key must be expanded using a `$`.
Consider this set of commands:

```bash
> a[k]=k
> declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="k")
> declare -A A
> A[k]=k
> declare -p A
declare -A A=([k]="k" )
> [[ -v a[k] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v A[k] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v a[j] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v A[j] ]] && echo true || echo false
false
> j=k
> [[ -v a[j] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
> [[ -v A[j] ]] && echo true || echo false
false
> [[ -v A[$j] ]] && echo true || echo false
true
```

Comment: I do not follow `Where can I leave out the $, where must I use the $`. Please define your definition of "correct result". The code output you posted is "correct". I do not understand what is confusing to you, could you explain it? Which output do you think is not "correct"? Maybe you are missing that https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays -> `The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number`, and in arithmetic expression you don't have to use `$`.

Comment: One of the confusing things is that `a[i]` seems to be treated the same as `a[$i]`, but it seems if `i` is not a number, then I need the `$`. The other thing is: Is `${a[$i]}` the same as `a[i]` in that context?

Comment: The dollar sign is optional in arithmetic contexts. My vague recollection is that this is reasonably documented, though probably somewhat obscurely if you are not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: @tripleee Can you be more specific about *where* it is documented?

Comment: I went over the [reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual) but it is indeed very spare around this topic. Not sure where exactly I picked this up; https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Not my downvote, but griping about individual drive-by downvotes is usually pointless - whoever downvoted will long have moved on and is unlikely to return here to read your rant.

Comment: The last two examples, with`${a[$i]}`, are testing something very different from what you think. They both expand `${a[$i]}` and test *the result of that* to see if it's a variable. In both versions, `${a[$i]}` expands to the empty string, so the test is equivalent to `[[ -v '' ]]`, which is false because the empty string is not the name of a defined variable.

Comment: `On "The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number"` I think understand what you mean, note that this is _documentation_, not specification. I think it would be nice to add like "If this is an indexed array, then subscript is an arithmetic expression, but if it's associative, then it's taken literally" or something smarter. I think people kind of understand it, but indeed I agree that documentation is ambiguous. At best, create a patch to fix it, or write to https://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group=bash .

Answer (score 3):

> One of the confusing things is that a[i] seems to be treated the same as a[$i], but it seems if i is not a number, then I need the $

From https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays :

> The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number

From https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic :

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. [...] A null value evaluates to 0. [...]

From that:

```
a[1]=''
i=1
[[ -v a[i] ]]    # Arithmetic expression `i` evaluates to 1.
                 # Element a[1] exists. True.
  
[[ -v a[$i] ]]   # `$i` is expanded -> [[ -v a[1]  ]]
                 # Arithmetic expression `1` evaluates to 1.
                 # Element a[1] exists. True.

[[ -v a[$j] ]]   # `$j` is expanded -> [[ -v a[] ]]
                 # Arithmetic expression '' evaluates to 0. (a null value evaluates to 0)
                 # Element a[0] does not exist. False.

i=0
[[ -v a[$i] ]]     # Expands to [[ -v a[0] ]]
                   # False, a[0] does not exist

[[ -v ${a[$i]} ]]  # Expands to [[ -v '' ]]
                   # False, variable with empty name does not exist.

i=1
[[ -v ${a[$i]} ]]  # Expands to [[ -v 0 ]]
                   # False, variable named `0` does not exist.
```

This is unrelated to `[[`. You can do `echo "${a[i]}" "${a[i + 1]}"` or `echo "$(( ))"`. What `[[` does is disables word splitting and filename expansion on the *words* that are it's arguments.

Note that for example, in the first case, the `[[` builtin receives 4 arguments `-v` `a[i]` `]]`. `i` is not expanded. Then, `[[` builtin *internally* handles the `a[i]` expression. In that sense, `[[ -v` is super special, where the "expansion" of the expression `i` inside `a[i]` "happens" inside the command after the builtin was called.

> Where can I leave out the $, where must I use the $, and where can I use the $ inside [[ (without affecting the correct result)?

Note that `$(( $i ))` is effectively *double* expanding:

```
a=123
b=a
$(( $b ))   # expands to $(( a ))
            # evaluates `a` to 123
```

You usually *want* to leave out `$` inside arithmetic expression. Also, there are associative arrays, for which `a[$i]` and `a[i]` has different behavior, as the part of `[<here>]` is no longer an arithmetic expression. So where you "can" leave out depends on the behavior *you* want to get. Working with indexed arrays, you want to just `a[i]`.

Comment: I wonder whether the documentation "*The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number*" is still up-to-date, considering that all BASH arrays are implemented as associative arrays anyway.

Comment: Another issue is "parameter expansion" in "parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated": Do they mean the *explicit* one (using `$`), or do they mean the *implicit* one (like in `(( ++i ))`)?

Comment: `"The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number" is still up-to-date,` I understand that this description in Bash manual is specifically about indexed arrays, as the above code part is about indexed arrays, it is up-to-date. `Do they mean` Explicit, this is my  "double expanding" comment: in `$(( $b ))` the `$b` is expanded _before_ `$((...))` starts computation.